# Why is there no try catch block for calling static void main()

Tags: java, exception

While I was going through the [JLS 8 11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2) I came across the following rule:

> The Java programming language requires that a program contains
>   handlers for checked exceptions which can result from execution of a
>   method or constructor (§8.4.6, §8.8.5). This compile-time checking for
>   the presence of exception handlers is designed to reduce the number of
>   exceptions which are not properly handled. For each checked exception
>   which is a possible result, the throws clause for the method or
>   constructor must mention the class of that exception or one of the
>   superclasses of the class of that exception (§11.2.3).

I can't get the point of that rule. For instance, I understand that both programs

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/R50HnD)

and

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try{
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Expection e){ }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/O1pHPj)

are well-formed.

But the rule requires that a program contains handlers for any checked exception that is not true for the first one. Actually, look at the definition of the handler:

> Every exception is represented by an instance of the class Throwable
>   or one of its subclasses (§11.1). Such an object can be used to carry
>   information from the point at which an exception occurs to the handler
>   that catches it. ***Handlers are established by catch clauses of try
>   statements (§14.20).***

Emphasize mine.

So, in the first program there is no any handler but

> The Java programming language requires that a program contains
>   handlers for checked exceptions

Couldn't you clarify this rule?

Comment: throws is basically to pass the exception to caller. so that caller can handle   in his own manner. and in second code you don't need throws actually!

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257174/how-does-the-jvm-handle-an-exception-thrown-by-the-main-method

Comment: " For each checked exception which is a possible result, the throws clause for the method or constructor must mention the class of that exception or one of the superclasses of the class of that exception " which it does. Whatis the mystery here?

Comment: @Raedwald What did you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in detail by [How does the JVM handle an exception thrown by the main method](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257174/how-does-the-jvm-handle-an-exception-thrown-by-the-main-method).

Essentially, this is done by the internals of the JVM - so therefore exempt of any JLS rules. You can override this behaviour if you wish.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("I caught it !" + e);
        }
    });
    throw new Exception();
}
```

I can't find any formal specification for this other than [JLS execution chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) that only covers definition of main(). It is possible it doesn't exist, not all of the world is nicely documented. [The c code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/raw-file/jdk7-b24/src/os/linux/launcher/java.c) for the java runner uses JNI. This should give you an idea what is happening and why the JLS is irrelevant here.

```
/* Build argument array */
mainArgs = NewPlatformStringArray(env, argv, argc);
if (mainArgs == NULL) {
    ReportExceptionDescription(env);
    goto leave;
}

/* Invoke main method. */
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, mainClass, mainID, mainArgs);

/*
 * The launcher's exit code (in the absence of calls to
 * System.exit) will be non-zero if main threw an exception.
 */
 ret = (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env) == NULL ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm looking for a normative reference. It would be good if you provided one.